# Fetching data from multiple service on single component using RXJS in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have two services with

ser1.

```
  getdata1() {
    this.http.get<{message:string,Data1:any}>('http://localhost:3000/api/1')
      .pipe(map((data1)=>{
        return Data1.Data1.map(data=>{
          return  {
            id: data._id,
            data1Title:data1.data1Title,
          }
        })
      })).subscribe((data1) => {
        this.data1=data1
        this.serv1Subject.next([...this.data1])
      })
  }

  getData1Listener() {
    return this.serv1Subject.asObservable()
  }
```

ser2

```
  getdata2() {
    this.http.get<{message:string,Data2:any}>('http://localhost:3000/api/2')
      .pipe(map((data2)=>{
        return Data2.Data2.map(data=>{
          return  {
            id: data._id,
            data2Title:data2.data1Title,
          }
        })
      })).subscribe((data2) => {
        this.data2=data2
        this.serv2Subject.next([...this.data2])
      })
  }

  getData2Listener() {
    return this.serv2Subject.asObservable()
  }
```

Now on componentx i need to fetch the data1 and data2 in nginit and after the data is available need to perform an functionY

How can i use subscribe to trigger an functionY?

In componentx.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.Service1OberableSubject = this.serv1.getData1Listener().subscribe((data1) => {
      this.data1 = data1;
    })
    this.Service2OberableSubject = this.serv2.getData2Listener().subscribe((data2) => {
      this.data2 = data2;
    })
    this.serv1.getdata1()
    this.serv2.getdata2()
  }
```

Comment: 1) Are you using the result from the request in another place for which you are using subject? 3) Does function Y require the result of both the api or just need to execute after the completion of two api?

Comment: @j4rey 1. No those are independent request 2. yes function y requires both return data from services

Comment: but are you using the response anywhere else other than passing it to function Y? I see you are storing the result in multiple places a) in data variable and b) in Subject.

Comment: No those services do cater in different componets but i am mapping both in componentX to render all together

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forkJoin` from `rxjs`.

`import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';`

#### component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  forkJoin([this.serv1.getData1Listener(), this.serv2.getData2Listener()]).subscribe(data => {
    this.data1 = data[0];
    this.data2 = data[1];

  });
}
```

Comment: `forkJoin` will only complete once all its input Observables are completed, what most likely wouldn't  happen in this context, since both `this.serv1.getData1Listener()` and `this.serv2.getData2Listener()` are `Subject`s (unless they are unsubscribed_

Answer (score 1):

Possibly something like this. Use `tap` to tap into the response and do anything needed.
And `forkJoin` will merge the response and give it in an array, the first index will the be response of the first observable that was passed in.

```
getdata1() {
    this.http.get<{message:string,Data1:any}>('http://localhost:3000/api/1').pipe(
        map((data1)=>{
            return Data1.Data1.map(data=>{
              return {
                id: data._id,
                data1Title:data1.data1Title,
              }
            })
        }),
        tap((data1)=>{
            //save to data1 if needed
            this.serv1Subject.next([...this.data1]))
        })
    )
}

getdata2() {
    this.http.get<{message:string,Data2:any}>('http://localhost:3000/api/2').pipe(
        map((data2)=>{
            return Data2.Data2.map(data=>{
                return  {
                    id: data._id,
                    data2Title:data2.data1Title,
                }
            })
        }),
        tap((data2)=>{
            //save to data2 if needed
            this.serv2Subject.next([...this.data2]))
        })
    )
}


forkJoin(
    getdata1(),
    getdata2()
).subscribe((x:any[])=>this.functionY(x));
  
functionY([a, b]){
    console.log({a: a,b: b});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can have if implemented:

```js
import { zip } from 'rxjs';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.serv1.getdata1()
  this.serv2.getdata2()

  zip(this.serv1.getData1Listener(), this.serv2.getData2Listener())
  .pipe(first())
  .subscribe(([data1, data2]) => {
     this.data1 = data1;
     this.data2 = data2;

     functionY(data1, data2)
  })

}
```

Comment: After ngOnInit() the next on getData1Listener & getData2Listener doesn't work

Comment: both  `getData1Listener` and  `getData2Listener` each has to emit value in order for `zip` to emit

Comment: ok so i have 2 different services after calling function in one service how can i hit next on another service?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the issue, In your example `this.serv1.getdata1()` calls next on the first subject
and   `this.serv2.getdata2()` calls next on the second

Comment: if i add data on service 1 i will be hitting next on service1 only service2 next will took place when i add data on service2. i want to hit next on other service when i add data to different service

Comment: do you want it to be bidirectional, meaning each will trigger the other?

Comment: Each time you call next on one subject you can call next on the second, although this is not advisable

Answer (score 0):

forkJoin should be the  best operator in this scenario. It is equally important to understand other higher order operators, this will help to know when to use those.
For e.g.

**concatMap** — helps to map observables in sequence while waiting for previous observable to complete. The best use case would be a sequential form save.

**mergeMap** — helps mapping of observables running in parallel. All the previous Observables are kept alive.

**switchMap** — switchMap is the way to go if we want to cancel previous subscriptions. Type-ahead feature is best implemented using switchMap combined with deboundTime() and distinctUntilChanged().

**exhaustMap** — used for ignoring newly emitted values till ongoing observable is complete. Best used when we are saving data on click of a button, which has a probability of being clicked multiple times.

Comment: how can i use mergeMap here?